# How do you nest a select inside of another select using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Html doesnt allow to do the next:

```
<script>
  function openwindow(){
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "<select><option>etc</option>
</select>"
  }
</script>

<select onmouse = "openwindow()">
  <option id = "a" value = "a">A        
  </option>
</select>
```

So basiclly what im trying to do is nesting another select inside another select.

Obviously this cant be done like this, does any one has an idea how this can be done or if I use something like jQuery (i am not familliar with it) how can it be done?

Thanks.

[image: megamenu]

I couldnt find a one that explains it in the best way, but you can see that every category has an option for subcategories.

Comment: `<select>` inside another `<select>` in **invalid markup**. Why are you trying to accomplish this?

Comment: I am trying to categorize my products and I want a user friendly way for them to choose the kind of item they want. I tried building another select not in the same one and it looked kinda bad. So I am trying to open another select when the mouse is over the product type they want that has sub-categories

Comment: If you want to categorise your options you could use `optgroup`. Here is a simple example of how to do that.  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp

Comment: I am using shopify for my site and I saw this app, Mega Menu, that has these stuff and tried to do it myself with my own theme. So already looked at the optgroup and that wasnt the one I was looking for but thank you

Comment: @EladGoldenberg then maybe you might want to think about creating your own drop down or maybe look for a site that already has some created for you to use? I'm sure you will find many examples and tutorials online.

Comment: I am more into improving my knowledge but if I won't find any answer then it will come to that

Answer (score 0):

There is no `onmouse` event only. You could use `onmouseover` or something in Mouse Events category on [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events_examples.asp).

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question how to categorise the options, this is a minor correction to one of the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't append a `<select>` to a `<select>`, as doing so would result in [**invalid markup**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110705/the-select-element.html).

To seperate out your different types of content, you can make use of an **[`<optgroup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup)**:

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Or, alternatively, you could **build** a **new** `<select>` box upon the user selecting a particular option. In the following example, selecting `Mercedes` will create a secondary select box to choose a Mercedes model from:

```js
//Create array of options to be added
var array = ["Mercedes 1","Mercedes 2","Mercedes 3","Mercedes 4"];

//Create and append select list
var selectList = document.createElement("select");
selectList.id = "mySelect";
var target = document.getElementById('new');


//Create and append the options
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = array[i];
    option.text = array[i];
    selectList.appendChild(option);
}

var selection = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
selection.onclick = function() {
  if (selection.value == 'mercedes') {
    target.appendChild(selectList);
  }
}
```

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

<div id="new"></div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I looked a little more in w3s  and found this:   <script>
function mouseCords(event) {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;  
}
Maybe I can open the other select where those cords are? And is there a way for the cords to update automaticaly? seeing their "try it" showed me that when my cursor goes off and then back on just then it updates the location

Comment: You **can't** use mouse co-ordinates to open a `<select>` box at a specific position; it **must** be inserted into the DOM. However, what you can do is use CSS to **position** the element that it is inserted to. In my example, `#new` will only contain the generated `<select>` box. If you **really** wanted to, you could position `#new` relatively, and use negative margins to adjust exactly where it appears on the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is only an idea.

Say you have 2 selects with id=`se1`, id=`se2`

Now assume we show `se1` first
Then on hover of a `se1`'s option, show `se2` select - just beside the `se1` select.
Then on an option selection in `se2`, hide `se2`

This can work if you have different selects (like `se2`) for different options of `se1`

You can create a inner selects dynamically, using `document.createElement("SELECT")`, see this - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp

Now, this can go any number of levels.
To correctly place, the `select`s for multi-level, without going out of screen, see https://popper.js.org/

You can also have `div` with some `a`s instead of `select` elements - see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick_dropdown

Often Context menu have nested selects, See below ones for some ideas:
- https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core/components/context-menu
- https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=contextmenu
- https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/layout/menu/context-menu/

Hope this helps, else ping in comments on more discussion & implementation.